# Error occurring while doing the meteor with d3js from meteor tutorial

Tags: meteor

I did the examples from meteor web site[meteor offical website](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) . First 3 chapter i got the output which exactly same as the tutorial . But after these chapter i got error. Because i don't have data. From where we will get the data? How can we get the data?`

Comment: d3js? wich tutorial are you looking at?, the tutorial from the official website its Todo app right?